# How do I use an HTML text input to set a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set up a text input box on a webpage that sets a JavaScript variable, however I can't seem to figure it out. Google hasn't helped, I'll I've found from my searches was how to set an input box's text using javascript, which is the opposite of what I need.

Here's what I've got:

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function() {
        var searchterm;

        searchterm = "error";

    searchterm = document.getElementById("searchbox");

  };
};
```

What I want this code to do: Take the content of the input box with the ID "searchbox" whenever I hit "submitButton" and use it as the variable "searchterm", running all of my code over again with the new variable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're just missing a `.value`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes

Comment: What do you mean by *running all of my code over again with the new variable*?

Comment: Are you trying to use `searchterm` outside of the function or just inside it?

Comment: So far, the code runs once when the page loads, and then refuses to run again when I press the button, but I want the code to run over again with the new variable.
I've added the .value and moved the variable now, too.

Comment: Any code outside of that onclick function won't run as a result of the button being clicked. If you have a particular piece of Javascript code you want to re-run when the button is clicked, I'd suggest putting it into a function and calling that new function in the onclick as well as where it originally was in the code.

Comment: Okay, I've got it figured out. I had to add the .value, move the variable out of the onlick funtion, add a new funtion for the code I want re-run, and a couple syntax errors to fix.

Thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `value` from the search box. Try something like this:

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function() {
    var searchterm = "error";
    searchterm = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
};
```

If you need to use the variable `searchterm` outside the scope of the onclick function, just move the `var searchterm` declaration outside of that function.

Comment: No change in results. Clicking the button still has no affect on the page.

Comment: This code will simply get the value from the `searchbox` textfield and assign it to the `searchterm` variable. What are you trying to do to the page after getting that value? You might clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to use `searchterm` you have to move it out of the function scope.
Next just assign value to it:

`searchterm = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;`

So the final code would be:

```
var searchterm; //<-- if you want to make the variable accessible outside the function
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function() {
        //var searchterm;

        searchterm = "error";

    searchterm = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;

  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function() {
  window.searchterm = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
}
```

I use window object to assign it as global variable(it's really not advised to do) so you can access it from anywhere in your code.

And now you can access your variable like this:

```
var something = window.searchterm;
```